# Better way to build javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

Can I get a little advice on my js modules? I'm good with js, but not quite guru status :) Am I refactoring my modules right?

I've been using the js module pattern like this (rough example, I'm just worried about the structure):

**sloppy way?**

```
/* Module Code */
var MapModule = (function ($) {
    var $_address;
    var $_mapContainer;

    function loadApi() {
        // do something. maybe load an API?
    }

    function someInternalMethod() {
        // do other things
    }

    var pub = {};
    pub.setAddress = function (address) {
        $_address = address;
    };
    pub.getAddress = function () {
        return $_address;
    };
    pub.initialize = function () {
        loadApi();
    }
})(jQuery);

// usage
MapModule.initialize();
```

But that usage seems a little sloppy. I like constructors.

I refactored some modules like this:

**Better way?**

```
(function ($) {
    this.MapModule = function () {
        var $_address;
        var $_mapSelector;
        var $_mapContainer;
        function loadApi() {
            // do something. maybe load an API?
        }
        function someInternalMethod() {
            $_mapContainer = $($_mapSelector);
            // do stuff with the jQ object.
        }

        var pub = {};
        pub.setAddress = function (address) {
            $_address = address;
        };
        pub.getAddress = function () {
            return $_address;
        };
        pub.initialize = function (selector) {
            $_mapSelector = selector;
            loadApi();
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

var map = new MapModule();
map.initialize('#mapcontainer');
```

That usage seems a lot cleaner to me, and it works just fine, but am I going about it properly?

**Taking it another step**

Say this module does some stuff with a div that wraps Google Maps and jQuery functionality: Any tips on turning that into a jQ plugin so I can use it with a signature like `var map = $('mapcontainer').mapModule();`

Thanks!

Comment: This question seems to be heavily based on opinion, and I'm voting to close it as such. With that said, look at AMD and CommonJS module patterns (UMD is good too if you don't have dependencies) and give requirejs or browserify a try, they'll help to truly modularize your code.

Comment: Thanks, @zzzzBov. Yes, it is largely opinionated, in the sense that different developers will have different code styles and preferences. I think I'm looking at three different points in that range; specifically, **moving** among the three. Thank you for the additional keyword to my google-fu :) Much appreciated!

Comment: @zzzzBov, I would accept that comment as the answer if it was an option :)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your snippet and have actually implemented javascript revealing module pattern which gives the opportunity to implement public & private functions using closure.

Hope this will be helpful:

```
/* Module Code */
var MapModule = (function (module, $, global) {
    var $_address;
    var $_mapContainer;

    // Public functions
    function _loadApi() {
        // Do something, maybe load an API?
    }
    function _someInternalMethod() {
        // Do other things.
    }
    function _initialize = function () {
        _loadApi();
    }

    // Private functions
    function _setAddress = function (address) {
        $_address = address;
    };
    function _getAddress = function () {
        return $_address;
    };

    $.extend(module, {
        loadApi: _loadApi,
        someInternalMethod: _someInternalMethod,
        initialize: _initialize
    });

    return module;
})(MapModule || {},this.jQuery, this);

// Usage
MapModule.initialize();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku10mr0o/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this and thought I'd share my approach...

```
///////////////////////////////
// Module Code 
///////////////////////////////

var ExampleModule = (function()
{
    ////////////////////////////
    // Private Properties
    ////////////////////////////

    var whatever = {
        data: 'somedata';
    };

    ////////////////////////////
    // Private functions
    ////////////////////////////

    function _init() 
    {
        _loadApi();
        _bindToUIEvents();
    }

    function _loadApi() 
    {
        // load an api
    }

    function _bindToUIEvents()
    {
        $('#something').on('click', function(){

            // Do something cool

        });
    }

    function _getWhatever()
    {
        return whatever;
    }

    //////////////////////
    // Public API
    //////////////////////

    return{

        init: _init(),

        getWhatever: function()
        {
            return _getWhatever();
        }

    };

})();

// Usage
ExampleModule.init;
```